# In Corda Enterprise, No migration defined for schema error

Tags: corda

I have migrated our CorDapp from 3.1 OS to Enterprise and so far everything seems to be working well. The only issue I have encountered is with our Postgres integration. The process of linking up Postgres in open source was simply changing the `node.conf` to point towards a Postgres database and set up the DB roles correctly and everything worked well. I have followed the same process in Enterprise but am getting the following error:

> [ERROR] 12:19:57+1000 [main] internal.Node.run - No migration defined for schema: com.growadministration.ledger.schema.AccountApplicationSchema v1

I also setup a custom schema to see if that was the issue but I still get the same response. I have completely wiped the DB since using it for the Corda OS. Everything also works fine when using the default H2 database. I feel I have just missed a step and was wondering if anyone could identify the issue?

Answer (score 3):

In Corda Enterprise, the first time you install a new CorDapp on a node, you need to use the Corda Enterprise database management tool to to create the Liquibase file for each state schema. The process is documented here: https://docs.corda.r3.com/database-management.html#node-administrator-installing-a-cordapp-targeted-at-the-open-source-node.

This is because, since Corda Enterprise supports databases other than H2, it cannot let Hibernate simply create the database stuff itself, as it would in Corda Open-Source. Instead, Corda Enterprise supports automated database evolution.

Comment: Ah @Joel nothing entertains me more than thinking "that's just the problem I have - I wonder who else is facing this?" and seeing it was you and you've put it on the most google-able place one can find the solution.